# Asp.net pageBaseType error !

Tags: asp.net

I write base class,MyBase.cs, for asp.net pages. I want all asp.net page inherit from that base class instead of System.Web.UI.Page. So i configure in web.config as mention below.

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyBase">
```

Then i got following error message.

**Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl)**

Please help what shoul i do? do i need to inherits MyBase to every aspx pages.

My Web App running on .Net Framework 3.5SP1 & VS 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your ASPX page, the first line should have an *Inherits* attribute.  In your code behind, the first line of the class should be something like

```
//C#
public partial class NameOfPage : NameOfYourInheritedPageClass

//VB.Net
Partial Class NameOfPage
    Inherits NameOfYourInheritedPageClass
```

Make sure that the NameOfPage matches the target of the *Inherits* attribute.

Also make sure the AutoEventWireup="true" and CodeFile points to the corresponding code-behind file.

Comment: @Matthew - no worries.. wasn't worth another answer

Comment: aside: AutoEventWireup=true is a performance killer, you would be better off wiring the events explicitly in OnInit.